# how pass a function navigation.goBack() to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how i can pass a function navigation.goBack() to component child

Next code:

Parent

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ModalLoading visible={loading} />
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            innerRef={ref => scrollRef}
            contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
            style={styles.container}>

            <HeaderCadastro
                navigation={() => navigation.goBack()}
            />
```

Child

```
            <Pressable onPress={navigation} style={style.backButton}>
                <Icon name='chevron-back' size={moderateScale(30)} />
            </Pressable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your parent and child as this:
parent:

```
<HeaderCadastro  navigation={navigation.goBack} />
```

child :

```
<Pressable onPress={() => navigation()} style={style.backButton}>
                <Icon name='chevron-back' size={moderateScale(30)} />
            </Pressable>
```

explanation :

There were only syntax errors, not major issues.
You just to have to remember how to call it and how to pass it.